# How to bind a list in store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, microsoft-metro, store

I have problem with binding list in store apps.

```
public class Category
{
    public Category(int id, string name)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I created ColllecionViewSource and GridView

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="CategoriesViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CategoriesViewSource}}" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

In constructor of my page i add list of Category to CollectionViewSource

```
public HubPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
List<Category> test = new List<Category>();
test.Add(new Category(1, "two"));
CategoriesViewSource.Source = test;
}
```

But it doesn't work... What i do wrong?

Comment: Where is the CollectionViewSource located? And shouldn't the resources be in the resource section and use x:Key attribute to be found as static resourse?

Comment: CollectionViewSource is in Page.Resources section. I dont know what you mean about x:Key, CollectionViewSource have this atribute

Comment: StaticResource is usually found by x:Key attribute. ResourceDictionary uses it(x:Key) to index its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main problem is the use of x:Name attribute instead of x:Key that is supposed to be used - [What's the difference between x:Key and x:Name in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425571/whats-the-difference-between-xkey-and-xname-in-wpf) (it is for wpf but xaml and controls are nearly the same for win store apps)

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CategoriesViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
```

**EDIT**

Well, actually I am bit confused, because [resource by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633901/why-setting-xname-on-window-resources-items-does-not-work) and other docs pertained for WPF XAML say that `x:Key` should be used for resources, while [this WinRT XAML example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.issourcegrouped) shows the equivalent use of `x:Name`

But [MSDN also says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In general, x:Name should not be applied in situations that also use
>   x:Key. XAML implementations by specific existing frameworks have
>   introduced substitution concepts between x:Key and x:Name, but that is
>   not a recommended practice.

So, now I am not sure that it is source of problems.

**EDIT:**

Try to

```
HubPage: Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    { if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
          this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }

    ...

    public HubPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        List<Category> test = new List<Category>();
        test.Add(new Category(1, "two"));

         this.Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(test);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Category> _Categories;

    ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get {return this._Categories;}
        private set 
        {
            this._Categories = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Categories");
        }
     }
}

   <Page DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
   ...
   <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
```

Page is your main element in XAML.

Comment: <Page.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CategoriesViewSource" x:Name="CategoriesViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="True"/>

and still nothink :(

Comment: Have you tried to bind the collection directly(avoiding the CollectionViewSource)? And I thought that if msbuild is unable to find resource by key it should show an error. Does it show any errors or warnings?

Comment: Yes, i tried. Still nothing. <GridView x:Name="gridViewContent"> and after it gridViewContent.DataContext = test; 

I tried to manually enter the text to textBlock's but it also did not show up - this is normal when a GridView?

Comment: Well, your category class does neither implement INotifyPropertyChanged, nor it is the dependency object or having appropriate propertyChanged events

Comment: So what i must do? Implement interface NotifyPropertyChanged and implement event .PropertyChanged in my class?

Comment: One of the best thing to do is to not implement your collection creation in the code-behind. It could easily become far too messy(like the code I added now in my answer). Read about the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Just try to move all the Categories related code from code-behind file to a separate class. Then you could use instance of that class as the DataSource. It will be more coherent.